# Quaternion Rotation relative to world

Tags: rotation, quaternions

Unity3D offers the following method:

```
Rotate(eulerAngles: Vector3, relativeTo: Space = Space.Self);
```

For example, this will rotate the object around it's local X axis:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3(50,0,0) * Time.deltaTime, Space.Local);
```

If I first rotate 90 degrees around it's local y axis (which is up in unity) and then rotate it around the X axis relative to World, it will basically rotate around the local Z axis, ie:

```
//setup
transform.Rotate(Vector3(0, 90, 0));
//on update
transform.Rotate(Vector3(50,0,0) * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

In my own implementation, using quaternions, I have the local rotation implemented, which was easy.

```
//rotate around local axis
currentRotation *= rotateQuat;
```

How would I go about implementing the relative to world behaviour using quaternions?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a way to do it in Unity without explicit calculations, but...

When using quaternions for rotation, it makes more sense to think in terms of a rotation (angle a) around a specific axis (unit vector u) rather than using Euler angles; the quaternion itself (actually a unit quaternion, or "versor") can be represented as a 4-vector (w, x, y, z), where w = cos(0.5*a) and (x, y, z) = (u_x, u_y, u_z) * sin(0.5*a) (meaning a = 2 * arccos(w) and u = (x, y, z) / sin(0.5*a) = (x, y, z) / sin(arccos(w)) ). Following from this, the "identity" quaternion (i.e. no rotation) is (1, 0, 0, 0), as cos(0) = 1 and sin(0) = 0, and very usefully, the inverse/conjugate of a quaternion, (w, -x, -y, -z), represents the opposite rotation (x, y, and z are technically imaginary components; you can also represent a quaternion as w+x*i+y*j+z*k). To apply a rotation to a point p in 3D space using a quaternion, you use p' = (w, x, y, z)*(0, p_x, p_y, p_z)*(w, -x, -y, -z), where the multiplication is performed as shown here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Ordered_list_form

Thus, performing a world-relative rotation with a quaternion given an already-existing rotation represented by a quaternion is relatively simple if you know what the angle and axis of rotation (in world space) are for the new rotation, as the main addition to the computation is to apply the conjugate of the existing quaternion to the axis of rotation for the new quaternion in order to represent that axis in local/object space; then you just create the quaternion for the new rotation and apply it to the existing one (I'm not sure how Unity orders quaternion composition, but normally if you apply q1 followed by q2 the composed quaternion would be q2*q1 [quaternion multiplication is non-commutative], so it should be something like `resultQuat = newQuat * prevQuat;`).

Comment: Hmm I think I get it and tried a lot, but it doesn't work out for me... What do you mean by "apply the conjugate of the existing quaternion to the axis of rotation of the new quaternion"? I tried `mRotation = Quaternion(angle, x, y, z) * conjugate(mRotation) * mRotation` but it just turns 90 degrees when it should just turn a couple degrees on each update(quaternion parameters are PI * deltaTime, 0, 0, 1)

Comment: PS: I'm not using Unity, i just wanted to provide that as an example

Comment: @cboe assuming `(x, y, z)` is the (normalized) axis of rotation in world space, and the software you are using doesn't do any fancy behind-the-scenes stuff when multiplying quaternions together, you'd use something like `localAxisAdjusted = conjugate(mRotation) * Quaternion(0, x, y, z) * mRotation * sin(0.5 * angle)`, and then apply the new rotation using `Quaternion(cos(0.5*angle), localAxisAdjusted.x, localAxisAdjusted.y, localAxisAdjusted.z)`.